# Knockout $parent and Typescript overridden function

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I have a typescript class B that inherits typescript class A.

class A has a KnockoutObservable called Model.

class A has a function called `GetSomeNumber()` that returns a number

```
export class A{ 
    Model: KnockoutObservable<C>;
    constructor(){ this.Model = ko.observable(new C()); } 
    GetSomeNumber (): number { return 1; }
}
```

class B extends class A and overrides the function `GetSomeNumber()`.

```
export class B extends A{
    GetSomeNumber(): number { return 2; }
}
```

In a Knockout binding, I am referencing `$parent.GetSomeNumber()` on an element that is bound to the Model on an instance of class B.

I receive the following error though...

> Unable to get property 'GetSomeNumber' of undefined or null reference

It does work, however, if I remove the override from class B.

Comment: Also, when knockout binding, to make sure you get the correct ``this`` it is sometimes necessary to wrap your function call in an anonymous function, such as ``data-bind="click: function () { $parent.doSomething(); }``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GetSomeNumber function on class B was actually calling GetSomeNumber on one of class Bs members.  The member property had not been initialised at this point.  My class B was more like this...

```
export class B extends A{
   somethingElse: C

   constructor(something: C){
       this.somethingElse = something; 
   }

   GetSomeNumber(): number { return this.somethingElse.GetSomeNumber(); }
}
```

To fix the problem, I now check that somethingElse has been initialised...

```
export class B extends A{
   somethingElse: C

   constructor(something: C){
       this.somethingElse = something; 
   }

   GetSomeNumber(): number { 
      if(this.somethingElse)
         return this.somethingElse.GetSomeNumber(); 
      else
         return 0;
   }
}
```

The reason for the confusion was that the function on class C had the same name as the function on class B, so I misinterpreted the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly class B is not initialized. Make sure `class B` is included *after* `class A` e.g. check the order in the script tags or if using `--out` check the ordering in your `reference.ts`

Comment: The ordering seems fine.  If I remove the GetSomeNumber function from class B it works.